# Change Zoom Level and Location on Folium Map HTML Object

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I am working on a project where I provide a Folium Map as an HTML file in an iframe. The map is generated once a week and then the HTML file is presented through the iframe bacause of how long it takes to generate all of the ponts and clusters.

I am looking to integrate a search functionality where I can have a user search for a location, and then the zoom level and center location changes to the location they searched for. Is there a way to accomplish this / is this possible since I am serving it as an HTML file instead of an object?

The map is being generated using: `ex_map = folium.Map(location=starting, zoom_start=8)` so I am looking for some way to change the 'starting' value to 'searched' where it is a different set of coords.

Changing the HTML itself before reloading the page as this same file is being served to several people at once on a web server. I have tried to look at opening the HTML file back as a Folium object but no avail.